# How to exit the first acquired freighter in own space ship?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Following the story line in NMS, I got the help signal from a freighter captain to protect his freighter against pirates. Eventually I got his freighter for free. It seems it now belongs to me.

My first task was to build a Fleet Command Room, what I have done.

Now I wish to exit this freighter with my own space ship (is waiting for me in the hangar). But whatever I try to do, I can't start my star ship and leave the freighter. The hangar doors are open - and close if I exit my star ship.

What exactly is necessary that I can leave the freighter?

Comment: Just to confirm, you get in the ship and try to take off like you would from a station, and nothing happens?

Comment: What happens when you press `W` for the normal takeoff?

Comment: @dpeif Yes, nothing happens. No message, no start, nothing. At polygnome Nothing. It seems that something is blocking my start. Unfortunateley I have no idea what or why...

Comment: Are you able to purchase a new ship that flies into your freighter bay?

Comment: @dpeif You ask if I can buy a ship from another "guest" in my freighter bay?

Comment: @PeterCo yep, just curious. Lots of weird bugs with weird fixes, might just "reset" your current ship. You could also take new ship to a planet and summon your ship that cant undock, if that's an option.

Comment: Since I could not find a solution I jumped back to previous savegame. In my fresh attempt to rescue the freighter from pirates, everything works fine. I have no idea what could have caused this previous blocking behaviour.